# Generating an ADODB recordset programmatically

Tags: .net, vb6, ado, recordset

I am attempting to generate an ADO RecordSet programmatically within .Net. This will be passed on to existing legacy code in VB6 which is already expecting a ADO RecordSet, I do not wish to change the existing code.

I was successful in defining fields within a new RecordSet

```
ADODB.Recordset rs = new Recordset();
            rs.Fields.Append("Height", DataTypeEnum.adInteger, 4, FieldAttributeEnum.adFldMayBeNull, null);
```

within VB6 I can add records after calling Open on the RecordSet with no parameters:

```
rs.Open
```

when I try to call AddNew with in .net code it tells me the recordset must be open, and I can't call open because it is expecting the following parameters:

```
void Open(object Source, object ActiveConnection, CursorTypeEnum CursorType, LockTypeEnum LockType, int Options);
```

but I am attempting to load the RecordSet programmatically and do not have any active connection or other datasource.

What am I missing? 
Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those parameters are all optional in the [ADODB.Recordset.Open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675544(VS.85).aspx) method. Try explicitly passing the default values as specified in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675544(VS.85).aspx). There is one parameter, `Source`, with no explicit default listed. I imagine the default is `Nothing`. **EDIT** I guessed wrong, apparently it is `System.Type.Missing`

So the solution is:

```
rs.Open (System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing, _
  adOpenUnspecified, adLockUnspecified, -1)
```

Comment: Close...replace Nothing, or null with System.Type.Missing and it works beautifully. Thanks

Comment: @benPearce I edited my answer, is that now correct? (For anyone who stumbles across this in future)